# Where to listen to Prager Deutsch online?

Tags: dialect, audio

Is Prager Deutsch still spoken?  If so, where can I listen to it?  Best of all would be a podcast in Prager Deutsch, but absent that, long-running recordings (e.g. stories, newscasts, etc.) would be good too.

I've Googled for this, but have not found anything.  (I hope that the reason for this is that such material does not label itself self-consciously as Prager Deutsch.)

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist anymore as spoken language.<sup>[(1)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prager_Deutsch)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful CD by LENKA REINEROVÁ, the Prague author, reading from her own works. Unfortunately, I cannot find details right now.

Comment: Do you mean *Mandelduft. Erzählungen*? Wikipedia [says](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenka_Reinerov%C3%A1#Werke): "auch als CD, gelesen zusammen mit Danuta Görnandt. Der Audio Verlag, Berlin 2005. Apparently it can be bought on various online book marketplaces.